# How do I make controls extend passed a control bound or overlap with others?

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, custom-controls

I have a wpf grid setup where I have two custom buttons that are next to each other. First picture is how the design window looks like, however, functionally, it looks like the second picture. I want them to function like the grid doesn't block them (closely resembling the first picture.)

The current xml I have is based on [this MSDM](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/08a2aad9-f907-43eb-b466-7b6574e1a2ba/how-to-create-custom-shaped-buttons-in-wpf?forum=wpf) which is very basic.

[image: Grid is in blue, buttons are black]
[image: Grid is in blue, buttons are black]

I do not know how to proceed. Do I have to use a different control panel/container or is there a setting to allowed them to extend passed the grid if the other button isn't above it (like zpanel?)

E: I couldn't find any other questions for this, so please link to any searches/posts with information on it.

Comment: I don't see this would be possible.  One must overlap the other.  Maybe you could do something with images that have transparency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I can use canvas and just do a bit more xml to keep the design the same. I would still like to know if it is possible to overlap them in any way for future use.